# Create an array of months and year in rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, date, select

I need to create an array like this

["January 2020, February 2020, March 2020, April 2020, May 2020, June 2020, and so on till last month]

With Date::MONTHNAMES, it enumerizes only the months but I don't find a way to add the years.
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-map) method.

```
month_names = Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.map{ |m| "#{m} #{Time.zone.now.year}" }
p month_names
#=> ["January 2021", "February 2021", "March 2021", "April 2021",
     "May 2021", "June 2021", "July 2021", "August 2021", "September 2021",
     "October 2021", "November 2021", "December 2021"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map it and add the current year, something like this  `Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.map{ |month| "#{month} #{Date.current.year}" }`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
def month_names(year)
  1.upto(12).map |month|
    Date.new(year, month).strftime("%b %Y")
  end
end
```

While this seems like overkill compared to simple string concatention you can easily swap out [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) for the I18n module to localize it.

```
def month_names(year)
  1.upto(12).map |month|
    I18n.localize(Date.new(year, month), format: :long)
  end
end

# config/locale/pirate.yml
pirate:
  date:
    formats:
      long: "Aargh! it be the on the fair month of %m %Y"
```